# emacs lisp expand-file-name to string

Tags: elisp

```lisp
    (setq jedi:server-args
          '("--sys-path" "/usr/lib/python3.6"
            "--sys-path" "/home/jerryzhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"))
```

worked well, but I want use `$HOME` replace `/home/jerryzhang/` for more general. So I guess can use `expand-file-name`：

```lisp
(setq jedi:server-args
          '("--sys-path" "/usr/lib/python3.6"
            "--sys-path" (expand-file-name "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")))
```

but it not same as I thought, looks like `expand-file-name` not execute.

*sorry, I am not leaned lisp, but as an emacser.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use a backquote to substitute the result into the list, eg.

```
(setq jedi:server-args
      `("--sys-path" "/usr/lib/python3.6"
        "--sys-path" ,(expand-file-name "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")))
```

This is commonly used in lisps -- see [elisp backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```lisp
 (setq jedi:server-args
          (list
           "--sys-path" "/usr/lib/python3.6"
           "--sys-path" (expand-file-name "~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages")
           ))
```

via: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/c77h9m/how_emacs_lisp_expandfilename_to_string/